# How can I apply Next.js to a React project created with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'd tried to figure out how to use server side rendering (SSR) on my existing react, and I found Next.js which is a SSR framework for React.

Also, there is `create-next-app` to easily create Next.js app like CRA. As I already have my existing React project, I need to make it compatible with Next.js. But, they have quite different project architecutre.

I attached two architectures of `create-next-app` and `create-react-app` each with images below. As Next requires the folder `pages`, I feel like I need to move my components in that folder, but I'm confused about `src` and `public` folder in `create-react-app`.

Can anyone help me how can I apply Next.js to an existing React app?

**create-next-app**

[image]

**create-react-app**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Next js by adding 'next' package to your CRA. However, you would have to refractor part of your codebase. The src folder should contain a subfolder called 'pages', consisting of your paths.

Visit the [Next JS Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages) for more